# How to access to data attribute handling different input?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following list:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-pills-warning nav-pills-icons justify-content-center" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" data-role-slug="admin" href="#" "="" role="tablist">
            <i class="material-icons">supervisor_account</i> Admins                   
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active show" data-toggle="tab" data-role-slug="operator" href="#" role="tablist">
            <i class="material-icons">person</i> Operators                   
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I need to get the attribute `data-role-slug` I actually get the value in the following way:

```
$('a[data-role-slug]').on('click', function (e) {
    let roleSlug = $(e.target).data('role-slug');
    console.log(roleSlug);
});
```

the method works well, the only problem happen when the user click on the `<i>` tag inside the `<a>` tag, in that case the `roleSlug` will be `undefined`.

Is there a way to handle this issue without hard code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `this` inside the event handler. It will be the `<a>` instance the event occurred on regardless of what child is targeted

Or alternatively `e.currentTarget` will return the same instance as well

```
$('a[data-role-slug]').on('click', function (e) {
    let roleSlug = $(this).data('role-slug');
             // OR $(e.currentTarget).data('role-slug');
    console.log(roleSlug);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

That's because the target of an event is the element that actually received it, not the one is bubbled up to.

However you can try to be sneaky, maybe try something like this ?

```
$('a[data-role-slug]').each((index, element) => {
    element.on('click', () => {
        let roleSlug = element.data('role-slug');
        console.log(roleSlug);
    });
});
```

Alternatively you can use the `.parent` method to find the right element

```
$('a[data-role-slug]').on('click', function (e) {
    let roleSlug = $(e.target).data('role-slug');
    if (!roleSlug) {
        roleSlug = $(e.target).parent('a[data-role-slug]').data('role-slug');
    }
    console.log(roleSlug);
});
```

Comment: is there a way to avoid iteration?

Comment: Made an edit to suggest another solution not using iterations

Comment: Over complicating a simple and very common situation